# Image not loading in canvas js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm making a webpage with a canvas with an image inside, but the image never shows, and I don't find the problem in the code.

```js
var lienzo = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var papel = lienzo.getContext("2d");
var oveja = new Image();
oveja.src ="oveja.jpg"
oveja.addEventListener("load", dibujar());

function dibujar() {
  papel.drawImage(oveja, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 150);
}

canvas {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>
      Mi reto en Canvas
    </h1>
    <canvas id="canvas1" height="700px" width="700px"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the expected result: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y9mz.png)

But it only draws the red square without the image, it doesn't show any error in the console.

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change `dibujar()` to `dibujar`. This way you're passing the function itself not the function's return value as an argument.

```js
var lienzo = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var papel = lienzo.getContext("2d");
var oveja = new Image();
oveja.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y9mz.png" // Here I changed the image so that the demo works
oveja.addEventListener("load", dibujar);

function dibujar() {
  papel.drawImage(oveja, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 150);
}

canvas {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>
      Mi reto en Canvas
    </h1>
    <canvas id="canvas1" height="700px" width="700px"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```